# Codeigniter : Not Found The requested URL /elocal/category/agriculture was not found on this server

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. Actually CI project run very well on local on windows7 OS. But I have installed Ubantu 14.04 OS On my system. Then I got the below error on browser:

**Not Found**
The requested URL /elocal/category/agriculture was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

After search I found, every time I have to write index.php in project url

NOT WORK -:localhost/elocal/category/agriculture

WORKING -: localhost/elocal/index.php/category/agriculture

Please help me ,How can I resolve this problem.

---

I got the solution: Open apache2.conf [ /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ] .

And Replace

< Directory /var/www/ >

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```

< /Directory >

To

< Directory /var/www />

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

< /Directory >

Comment: Have you added the .htaccess file in your project root folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about using uppercase character in your index file name, in Windows file with uppercase or lowercase name are same, but not in Linux.

Comment: There is no uppercase character problem in my index file name, I had checked.Amir